# Deploy Angular app to a remote IIS server

Tags: angular, iis, angular7

I am developing an Angular 7 (angular-cli) app, on a windows machine with VS Code.
To test this app in a real environment, everytime I make changes I am running 'ng build' and then I copy the dist folder to a remote server where I have running a IIS.
I would like to automate this process and change somehow the output directory of the angular.json outputPath option to this remote machine, but I can't find a working solution.
Could anyone help me, please?
PS: I need it working as I explained. Running angular app in a local IIS is not what I need, because I am loading an iframe of a web hosted at the remote machine, and I would have to configure XSS and who know what more ^^

Thank you!

Edit: typo

Comment: Does the `--output-path` flag of `ng build` not do what you need?

Comment: It would do, if I found the way to set a remote address, wich I have not, yet :(

Comment: you should also set --deploy-url and --base-href if you're outputting to a subfolder of IIS i.e. --deploy-url /somepath/ --base-href /somepath/

Comment: Well how are you “copying” the app to this remote server without an address?

Comment: @pixelbits, I have enough setting --base-href, this is something I am already doing. Thank you anyway for pointing out.

Comment: @Claies, I am copying the app by right clicking on dist folder, selecting the 'copy' option, and the going to the remote IIS folder, right click, and paste xD
The question is how do I set a remote url at angular.json file, so I can automate this process. Thank you!

Comment: Well if you can copy and paste the files in windows, then your folder has a local address, not a remote one.  Ultimately, you shouldn’t need to do what you are asking.

Comment: I have a remote desktop connection opened to this remote machine (same ip range if that helps), that's why I can copy/paste.
I must add that the process is not only copy/paste, I first zip the folder, copy, paste, unzip

Comment: seems like you need to set up an ftp service to the server then mount the remote system via ftp, then publish to the ftp location.